# How to remove blank dates from related table with DAX running total?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following table.

I want to make a running total of `Qty sold`, based on `Date Sold`. Products weren't sold until 2019.

[image]

It is linked to my date table here, notice the inactive relationship, as the main relationship is `Date Added to Stock`. So I will use `USERELATIONSHIP` for the running total:

[image]

I created a DAX running total like so:

```
Cumulative Sold = 
CALCULATE(  
    SUM(Data[Qty Sold]),  USERELATIONSHIP(CalendarTable[Date],Data[Date Sold]), 
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED(CalendarTable[Date]),
        ISONORAFTER(CalendarTable[Date], MAX(CalendarTable[Date]), DESC)
        
    )
)
```

However when I add this data to a table, I can see that there are figures all the way back to 2018. In the first row the date is null, and has a sum of 441. I guess these are blank dates from 2018, and some from late 2022 perhaps. There were no products sold in 2018, it should be 0.

My calendar table goes back to 2018, is that the issue? How can I avoid this?

[image]

I tried to add a filter, however the resulting figures are completely wrong and is not cumulative.

```
Cumulative Sold = 
CALCULATE(  
    SUM(Data[Qty Sold]),
    FILTER(CalendarTable, CalendarTable[Date] >= MIN(Data[Date Sold])
    USERELATIONSHIP(CalendarTable[Date],Data[Date Sold]), 
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED(CalendarTable[Date]),
        ISONORAFTER(CalendarTable[Date], MAX(CalendarTable[Date]), DESC)
        
    )
)
```

Any advice? Perhaps my DAX measure is incorrect?

Comment: Hello @SCool. Please check your data table(fact table) for consistency of data in date columns (Wrong format, out of range dates etc.. )Empty row is there to ensure referential integrity. There is some data in your data table which does not have corresponding row in Calendar Table. To summarize, It seems to be an ETL problem at first sight.

Comment: I would pay attention on allselected it’s a tricky function that changes context.

Comment: Do you want to get just a cumulative sold for a current year?

Comment: @Mik well the last couple of years would be good, just to have records of past performance of the products. I appreciate the data is not in the best format.

Comment: @OzanSen i will double check that in the morning.

Comment: @SCool Hi. I'm trying to understand why don't you want to use a simple syntax like -`CALCULATE(Sum(...), DATESBETWEEN (...),USERELATIONSHIP(...))` ? Also it's not obvious what do you want to gain from ALLSELECTED()? In your pictures it looks like ALLSELECTED()=ALL(), that's why you can get values with blank() dates.